# Beamer table of contents - display all subsections below section

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

In a latex-beamer document i added the following TOC-Definition:

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
   \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Inhalts\"ubersicht}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
   \end{frame}
}
```

Which produces a tree like this:

```
Section1
  SubSection1
Section1
  SubSection2
Section1
  SubSection3
Section2
  SubSection1
Section2
  SubSection2
```

Instead i would like it to look like this:

```
Section1
  SubSection1
  SubSection2
  SubSection3
Section2
  SubSection1
  SubSection2
```

How can i modify the TOC-Tree to make it look like i want?

**Solved - MWE:**

```
\tableofcontents[ 
    currentsubsection, 
    hideothersubsections, 
    sectionstyle=show/hide, 
    subsectionstyle=show/shaded, 
    ]
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem? I ask you for this MWE because I did some tests and couln't reproduce the behaviour mentioned; in fact, what I got in my examples was exactly the desired output.

Comment: For those who wondering : this magic is explained in `Beamer`'s manual, "10.5 Adding a Table of Contents", p. 98 (version 3.36).

Comment: Also see https://statisticaloddsandends.wordpress.com/2019/02/18/beamer-inserting-section-slides-before-each-section/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
\tableofcontents[ 
currentsubsection, 
hideothersubsections, 
sectionstyle=show/hide, 
subsectionstyle=show/shaded, 
]
```

does what i want!

Answer (score 11):

You can use in your preamble

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Contents}
  \tiny{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
  \end{frame}
}
```

Which produces something like that before every section

[image]

Comment: Nice theme, which one is it?

Comment: @ppr looks like a theme used at a specific institution, given the name in the right bottom: https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%95%CE%B8%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C_%CE%9C%CE%B5%CF%84%CF%83%CF%8C%CE%B2%CE%B9%CE%BF_%CE%A0%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BD%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BF

Comment: @Thanos, all the subsections are highlighted at the same time, is there a way to highlight only one of the subsection?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following code:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection, 
    hideothersubsections, 
    sectionstyle=show/shaded,
]
\end{frame}
}
```