# Beamer, overview of all the subsections of my current section

Tags: beamer

I would like to get for my beamer presentation, using smoothbars, the overview of all the subsections of my current section. I would like to see the subsections as how the sections look.

```
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
```

I've used the following code but I don't obtain the result :

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in smoothbars}
       {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\makeatother
```

Can somebody help ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Beamer table of contents - display all subsections below section](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28654) ?

Comment: The difference is that my problem is about the outertheme, not the table of contents.

Answer (score 8):

You can redefine the `headline` beamer template as defined in `beamerouterthemesmoothbars.sty` to use `\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal` instead of the default `\insertsubsectionhead`; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.6cm\relax}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Three}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Three}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Four}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Some zoomed images showing the headline for some frames in the first and second sections:

[image]

[image]