# Beamer template: navigation by subsections

Tags: beamer

I want the navigation-line to show Subsection1.1, Subsection1.2 , Subsection 2.1 and Subsection2.2 instead of just Section1 and Section2. How do I do that? 
\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol does not work for me.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol }

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1.1}
\subsection{Subsection1.2}
\section{Section2}
\subsection{2.1}
\begin{frame}
bla2.1
\end{frame}
\subsection{2.2}
\begin{frame}
bla2.2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87029/36296 what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigation bars are a tricky thing to play with. But beamer has some build-in abilities which might be close enough to what you would like to accomplish.

**Option 1:**

You can change the headline to display all subsections of the current section instead of the sections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
    \vskip-5.5ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1.1}
\frame{test}
\subsection{Subsection1.2}
\frame{test}
\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection2.1}
\frame{test}
\subsection{Subsection2.2}
\frame{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Option 2:**

In addition to the section:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
    \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-8.2ex%
    \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
    \fi%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
        \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=1.ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1.1}
\frame{test}
\subsection{Subsection1.2}
\frame{test}
\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection2.1}
\frame{test}
\subsection{Subsection2.2}
\frame{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]