# Beamer - Table of content before section page

Tags: beamer

I'm using Beamer with the Metropolis theme for a presentation. I'd like to display the table of contents before the section page, how can I do that?
I wrote this command that does what I need but unfortunately it works also on the starred sections, which I don't want to have a section page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}    

\AtBeginSection{
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\frame{\sectionpage}
}

\begin{document}
\section*{S1}
\frame{f1}
\section{s2}
\frame{f2}
\section{s3}
\frame{f3}


\end{document}
```

Comment: **(1)** Provide a so-called *minimal working example*, it's your fourth question...you know the drill **(2)** Have a look at the `beamer` manual - especially at section 10.2 (Adding Sections and Subsections). **(3)** This question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28654) shows use the commands that you probably need. **(4)** Also have a look at section 10.5 (Adding a Table of Contents).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\AtBeginSection` can specify a special code for starred sections using `[]`:

> ```
> \AtBeginSection[<code for starred sections>]{<code for non-starred sections>}
> ```

Therefore, in your case, to disable the automatic display for the table of contents for \section*, you can write:

```
\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{
\frame}{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\frame{\sectionpage}
}
```